# How to update multiple rows at the same time with one query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In cleaning a set of data, I came across several entries where there are multiples of a street name such as:

```
Canal St & Monroe St
```

and

```
Canal St & Monroe St (*)
```

In total I have 25 street names that are misrecorded as the street name followed by (*). I want to update all of the street names so that they are rewritten to drop the (*) and all read under the original street name. I can update like this:

```
UPDATE `Bikeshare_data.2019_bike_data`
SET from_station_name = 'Archer (Damen) Ave & 37th St'
WHERE from_station_name ='Archer (Damen) Ave & 37th St (*)'
```

and it works successfully, but I'd have to run 25 individual queries to do so. I'll also have to do the same for the end station name. Is there a way I can combine this into one query to update them all at once?

Comment: Note that in your example you are explicitly removing the `'(*)'` and not the `'(Damen)'`.  I assume that is actually what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
update `Bikeshare_data.2019_bike_data`
    set from_station_name = replace(from_station_name, ' (*)', ''),
        to_station_name = replace(to_station_name, ' (*)', ''),
    where from_station_name like '% (*)' or
          to_station_name like '% (*)';
```

Note:  This assumes that `' (*)'` does not appear anywhere else in the names.  That seems like a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace a field. Please test this query on a copy of your data first. Only if the fields ends with `(*)` this is replaced.

```
UPDATE
  `Bikeshare_data.2019_bike_data`
SET
  from_station_name  = replace(from_station_name ," (*)", "")
WHERE
  from_station_name like "%(*)"
```

If everyting after a open bracket should be removed, use this:

```
regexp_replace(from_station_name ,"^([^(]*).*$","\\1")
```

and `like "%(%"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the below code :

```
UPDATE
  `Bikeshare_data.2019_bike_data`
SET
  from_station_name  = replace(from_station_name,'(*)','')
```

Comment: Gave this one a test, but I'm still getting duplicates as opposed to the two being consolidated, now it looks like this:
Ashland Ave & Lake St 
Ashland Ave & Lake St (Temp)

Comment: I guess space to be added before the bracket. I see someone else has added it to my code and pasted at the bottom. Hope you got it right